# MultiSelect Dropdown with checkboxes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of values say barcodes. I need to populate the multiselect drop down with the array values with checkboxes. Couldnt get the proper solution. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Check this https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Comment: May help you https://jsfiddle.net/michaeldeongreen/22et6sao/9/

Comment: @PrasanthBendra I need it in a dropdown.

Comment: @AnushaBayya did you check my answer